# Tigase and xmpp, 1st offline message not getting received

Tags: xmpp, tigase

hi I am using **Tigase and xmpp** for chat application, everything is working fine except i am not receiving first offline message.

Eg: there are 2 users A and B, A send 3 messages to B but B is offline(i.e. app is in Not running state), but when B comes online **he receive only 2 messages(last 2)**, first message always get missed.

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: when user A sends 3 messages to user B ( offline ), before user B come online check your database table ( don't remember the name ) and make user there exists 3 xml stanza related to your 3 messages .....

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem, on client side we can't do anything for that as XMPP(Tigase) server automatically returns all the offline messages when user comes online. There might be some problem in Tigase server which is not returning the first message. Because all the offline messages you will receive in
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
and it can be checked first offline message is not returned by server.